# complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $f$ is analytic on disc $D(0,1)$ and $f(x)=\tan x$ , when $0 < x < 1$

then there is no $z$ in $D$ with $f(z)=i$.

Comment: Could you clarify the notation $D(0, 1)$? Does this mean the open disc with center $0$ and radius $1$?

Comment: yes.. the open disc with center 0  and radius 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the identity theorem we get $f(z)=\tan z$ for all $z \in D$.  If $\tan z=i$ for some $z$ we have $\sin z=i \cos z$.  Now we use $\sin^2 z+ \cos^2 z=1$ to get $1=0$. A contradiction.